# General: Does Kinetic.js provide painting of specific pixels?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

This is a general question about Kinetic.js from a developer with a Processing/Processing.js background.

When using Processing.js, I routinely set the color value of a specific pixel on the canvas.

```
set(x, y, color);
```

Very easy as you can see.  In my situation, for each y-value, any value for x may have a slightly different color value (or not at all).

When I look at Kinetic.js, I see that everything is an object and the closest I can find to drawing a pixel would be a 1x1 Kinetic.Rect.  This seems like it could be intensive if you have, for example, 1,000 Kinetic.Rect objects per y-value.

In addition, I do not need each pixel to be an "object", per se.  Though, I do like other benefits of Kinetic.js, such as layering and better transition and animation control.

Does Kinetic.js provide the means for more direct pixel painting and manipulation, ala Processing.js?

Thank you.

Comment: You could just draw directly on a layer with regular canvas syntax like context.beginPath() and or an arc or something. You can also create a custom shape and draw on that in the same manner.

Comment: That's definitely a thought, thanks.  So the 'row' of pixels, which are draw using the canvas context directly, would belong to a shape, which would belong to a layer for of my 'row' custom shapes.  Does that sound right?

Comment: sounds about right. Again, you can draw directly to the layer, unless you need a bunch of custom shapes. You can do layer.getCanvas() and then that will be your context.

Comment: EliteOctagon (+1) is right-on with the Kinetic custom shape object.  Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QU6Ew/  One small gotcha: custom shapes allow 1 fill() before becoming undraggable.  Since you need multiple fill()'s for multiple colors, your shape is undraggable--doesn't sound like that's an issue for you though.